# What is the inverse of "namesake"?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

A *namesake* is a person that is named after another person.  Is there a word or phrase to describe the reverse relationship?

> He is my namesake.  I am his _____.

Comment: related: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/54502/is-there-a-word-for-someone-with-the-same-name

Comment: The answer seems to be "eponym" given here: http://english.stackexchange.com/a/212607/77227